# No matching function call between classes

Tags: c++, class, function, compilation

I've written 2 classes (AVL and Stack for my Data Structures lecture) and I'm trying to call this function:
`int MyStack::Push(avlnode *x)` 
in a function of the AVL class:
     `trace.Push(temp);`
trace is a MyStack object
and temp a pointer to avlnode (which is a struct).
When I try to compile the code I get the following error:

`In member function 'int MyAVLTree::Insert(int)':`
`error: no matching function for call to 'MyStack::Push(MyAVLTree::avlnode*&)'`
`note: candidates are: int MyStack::Push(avlnode*)|`

Comment: How/where is `temp` declared?

Comment: Please post a complete test case (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: maybe the argument you give to the function is wrong because you give avlnode*& not avlnode* (according to compilator)

Comment: The error messages seem to be implying that you have two distinct types called `avlnode`, one of which is in the scope of `MyAVLTree`, and one of which is not. But I assume you'd notice if you were completely defining the type in two places . . . did you try to do anything clever with your `#include`s? Is it possible that the same type definition is getting `#include`d multiple times, within different scopes, or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your error with the snippets provided further down in this post.

My guess is that you've put a forward declaration in the wrong place, probably in the global scope near `MyStack` (so that you can use it inside of the mentioned class).

```
class avlnode;

struct MyStack {
  int Push (avlnode *) {return 0;} 
};
```

...

```
struct MyAVLTree {
  struct avlnode {
    /* ... */
  };

  MyAVLTree (MyStack& a)
    : a (a) 
  {}  

  int insert (int) {
    avlnode * p; a.Push (p);
    return 0;
  }

  MyStack& a;
};
```

...

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  MyStack   a;  
  MyAVLTree b (a);

  b.insert (123);
}
```

...

```
foo.cpp: In member function 'int MyAVLTree::insert(int)':
foo.cpp:20:27: error: no matching function for call to 'MyStack::Push(MyAVLTree::avlnode*&)'
foo.cpp:20:27: note: candidate is:
foo.cpp:9:7: note: int MyStack::Push(avlnode*)
foo.cpp:9:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MyAVLTree::avlnode*' to 'avlnode*'
```